# Different DataTables with one query?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datatable, dataset, oledb

Let's say I have two tables, `Customer` and `Customer_address`. To populate one datatable from a query is trivial, but is it possible to populate two different datatables via one join query?

Example:

```
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT a.CustomerID, b.CustomerEmail FROM Customer a INNER JOIN Customer_address b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID WHERE a.CustomerID = 3", this.connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Customer");
```

Now I have `CustomerID` and `CustomerEmail` in `ds.Tables["Customer"]`.

Is it possible to have `CustomerID` in `Tables["Customer"]` and `CustomerEmail` in `Tables["Customer_address"]` without making two distinct queries?

Comment: If you want to reduce the number of queries done try aggregating them into a stored procedure or some-such as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx):

*"Multiple Result Sets: 
If the `DataAdapter` encounters multiple result sets, it creates multiple tables in the DataSet. The tables are given an incremental default name of `TableN`, starting with "Table" for `Table0`. If a table name is passed as an argument to the Fill method, the tables are given an incremental default name of `TableNameN`, starting with "TableName" for `TableName0`."*

So no, you can't specify the correct table name for the second table since it's derived from the single parameter in `Fill`.